# Is there a way to disable overlapping appoinments in jfxtras ICaledarAgenda?

Tags: java, javafx, jfxtras

How do I disable the overlapping appointment property so users can not create new overlapping appointments from the Agenda?

Answer (score 0):

There is none, outside of changing the skin. The change should not be big though. What is the use case?

Comment: Thank you for answering. How do you suggest to change the skin? And what is the use case? I want to use the Calendar to display all the booking for a room so there should be no overlapping booking

Comment: Ah, overlap can be interpreted in two ways; first is in the rendering of two simultaneous appointments, these visually overlap in order to save space. I assumed you referred to that. But another is attempting to create a simultaneous appointment. The latter would not be possible to prevent, but you can decide not to accept the new appointment, after the user finished drawing it. There is a newAppointmentCallbackProperty for that.

Comment: And when the user is changing an appointment so it then overlaps, you can negate that by responding to changes in properties of the appointments. But it would not be difficult to an add changedAppointment callback to make that easier.